# How to apply css type rules to Styled Components in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Having the following html/css code that enables html elements to behave like a radio group:

```css
.radios .radio{
    background-color:#c5e043;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer
}

.radios input[type=radio]{
    display:none
}

.radios input[type=radio]:checked + .radio{
    background-color:#241009
}
```

```html
<div class="radios">
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="rGroup"  id="r1"  />
    <label class="radio" for="r1"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rGroup"  id="r2" />
    <label class="radio" for="r2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rGroup"  id="r3" />
    <label class="radio" for="r3"></label></div>
</div>
```

I want to write in React some Styled components that behave in the same way but don't know how to write in styled components `input[type=radio]` and `.radios input[type=radio]:checked + .radio`.

Here is the code, a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mopsa-t1cjzf?file=/src/index.js:0-1299). It shows the elements but click isn't working, it doesn't change the selected element like in the above code.

What should be changed?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const XSelectionBoxContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: #c5e043;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const Xlabel = styled.label`
  background-color: #c5e043;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const Xinput = styled.input`
  display: none;
  :checked {
    background-color: #241009;
  }
`;

function App() {
  const options = [
    {
      label: "first",
      value: "first",
      name: "radio-group"
    },
    {
      label: "second",
      value: "second",
      name: "radio-group"
    },
    {
      label: "third",
      value: "third",
      name: "radio-group"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <XSelectionBoxContainer>
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <div key={option.label}>
            <Xlabel htmlFor={option.value}></Xlabel>
            <Xinput
              type="radio"
              name={option.value}
              value="1"
              id={option.value}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </XSelectionBoxContainer>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `label` component below the `input` element so that you can use the `+` operator in css to style the label element if the `input` is `:checked`.

Updated code below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const XSelectionBoxContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: #c5e043;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const Xlabel = styled.label`
  background-color: #c5e043;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const Xinput = styled.input`
  display: none;
  &:checked { 
    & + label {
      background-color: #241009;
    }
  }
`;

function App() {
  const options = [
    {
      label: "first",
      value: "first",
      name: "radio-group"
    },
    {
      label: "second",
      value: "second",
      name: "radio-group"
    },
    {
      label: "third",
      value: "third",
      name: "radio-group"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <XSelectionBoxContainer>
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <div key={option.label}>
            
            <Xinput
              type="radio"
              name={option.name}
              value="1"
              id={option.value}
            />
            <Xlabel htmlFor={option.value}></Xlabel>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </XSelectionBoxContainer>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: it seems to make them clickable but doesn't work as a radio group, it should only have maximum one active at the time like in the html+css example. here is a sandbox with your answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mopsa-t1cjzf?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @LeoMessi, I have updated the code. the `Xinput` has a name attribute in which you were passing `{option.value}`. Change it to `{option.name}` to group it.